# If a function preserves all filter limit points it is continuous

Tags: general-topology, filters

In Pete L. Clark's [notes on convergence](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf) it is stated that (Proposition 5.14):

> For a set function $f:X \to Y$, if for every prefilter $F$ on $X$ with a limit point $x$, $f(F)$ has $f(x)$ as a limit point, then $f$ is continuous.

I've been unable to prove this, and I think I may have a counterexample:

- Take $X := \mathbb{N} + \infty$ (order topology) to $Y:=\mathbb{N} + \infty$ (order topology plus $\{\infty\}$ open). It seems to me that the identity map satisfies that it preserves all limit points but is not continuous.

Is my counterexample correct? If not, what's the error and what's a proof of the statement?

---

Edit: My counterexample is incorrect as shown by Daniel in the comments. I'm only missing the proof now.

Comment: The notes suggested the same thing, but I'm failing to see this. We only get that each neighborhood of $f(x)$ *intersects* every image of a neighborhood of $x$. I do agree, however that continuity is equivalent to preserving filters converging to points. I.e. if $F \to x$ then $f(F) \to f(x)$.

Comment: In your example, I think the filter generated by $\{ [n, \infty) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ would be a filter with limit point $\infty$ in $X$; but it doesn't have limit point $\infty$ in $Y$.

Comment: OK, so let's consider this argument for metric spaces and sequences as a starting point: suppose $f$ is not continuous.  That implies there is a sequence $x_n \to x$ where $f(x_n) \not\to f(x)$.  Therefore, there is some neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ does not contain $x_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.  So, there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which entirely misses $V$; that implies that this subsequence has limit point $x$ but $f$ applied to the subsequence does not have $f(x)$ as a limit point.  Now, I would try to convert this proof to filter language.

Comment: (Haven't checked viability of the translation in detail, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof (shared to me by someone else): If $U$ is a subset of $X$, and $c \in U$, then the filter generated by $U$ has $c$ as a limit point. Therefore (the filter generated by) $f(U)$ has $f(c)$ as a limit point, and therefore $f(U)$ too.

Comment: Ah ha, so if $U \ne \emptyset$, then this shows $f(\bar U) \subseteq \overline{f(U)}$; and that's also clearly true for the case $U = \emptyset$.  And that implies $f$ is continuous.